# Call with AK odds

Tags: odds

Say you are facing an all in with AKs and put your opponent on AA, KK, or QQ

What odds do you need to call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On related question I ran the numbers and thought it might be of value

Since you have blocker on AA KK you will see them less
1/4 AA
1/4 KK
1/2 QQ

Odds against those hands
AA 1/8.5
KK 1/3
QQ 1/2

In net (1/4/8.5 + 1/4/3 + 1/2/2) = 0.36

1 is pot and b is the bet you need to call
EV 
0 = -b + (1/4*1/8.5 + 1/4*1/3 + 1/2*1/2)*(1+2b)
b/(1+2b) =  (1/4*1/8.5 + 1/4*1/3 + 1/2*1/2)
(1+2b) / b = 1 / (1/4*1/8.5 + 1/4*1/3 + 1/2*1/2)
1 / b = 1 / (1/4*1/8.5 + 1/4*1/3 + 1/2*1/2) - 2

b = 1.32 of the pot
Or you need to be getting about 1.757:1

Comment: I think it's simpler to use the formula `2b + p = ob` where b is bet (your stack) `p` is pot and `o` is odds of losing.  `o` = (8.5 * 1/4) + (3 * 1/4) + (2 * 1/2) = 3.875.  Plugging that into the equation we get `p` = 1.875 or 15/8 which is close to what you got.  Am I missing something in this calculation?

Comment: When you say p = 1 simplifies, are you saying take the reciprocal?  You can calculate how small your bet needs to be in terms of the pot or how large the pot needs to be in terms of the bet.  I prefer the latter since it is easier (for me) to do multiplication in my head than division.

Comment: I'm relaxed (about this anyway.)  I thought you pointed that out because you felt it was important.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow your math.  Can you explain what is wrong with the approach I gave?  We are trying to calculate when the odds are even, right?

Comment: I think it's easier if I add an answer.  I'll do that later.  Can we do math markup on this site?

Comment: So I'm using the assumption that you should call when your EV is 1.

Comment: So how much of an edge over even odds are you looking for?  One chip or do you have a number/factor in mind?  It makes a difference in the calculation.  To keep it simple, I generally think in terms of if I am getting "at least even odds"  but that could be changed to "better than even odds" but it's the same calculation either way.  I also only play in person so I tend towards conservative estimates over exact calculations.  Can't really pull out my laptop at the table.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused.  Your question says "you are facing an all in" with an (i.e. one) opponent.  I assumed that meant you were being put all-in but either way, there's no more betting in that situation.  Can you clarify?

Comment: You should change the question because "all-in bet" has a very specific meaning that doesn't include most of what you just said is in scope but there isn't really one mathematical answer to that, though.  The odds for all-in are really exact and will be very different than when betting can continue.  Also your chances are affected by other players regardless of whether you 'fear' them.  They can catch cards.

Comment: Let what go?  There's no question what "all-in" means in poker.

Comment: I was planning on posting an answer but I'm not sure what the question is.  You had what appears to be a very clear question that has a very specific answer.  Your question says you are facing "an opponent" (singular) "all in bet" which either means the other player went all in or put you all in.  Then you say "last to act" which is a completely different question which doesn't seem answerable without more information about stacks and remaining players.  I think we're done here but I really don't understand what your goal is with this.

Comment: Yeah, completely different.  If it's all in, the odds in the pot plus the 2 bets are need to give you your odds.  You know exactly what you can win and what you are risking.  If there will be more betting, then there are implied odds, then there are other considerations as you obviously know.  This is basic stuff.  By EV 1 I mean 1 to 1 odds like the backing up your 'come' bet in craps.  You referred to it as 0 so I through you understood what I meant.

Comment: Just an FYI. Lengthy comment threads like these get the algo's pinging the mods, so Im going to copy/move this to the chat.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48575/discussion-on-answer-by-paparazzi-call-with-ak-odds).

Answer (score 2):

[propoker tools](http://www.propokertools.com/simulations) says:

```
Hold'em Simulation 82,190,592 trials (Exhaustive)
Hand    Equity  Wins    Ties
AxKx    34.59%  28,123,620  605,616
QQ+     65.41%  53,461,356  605,616
```

looks like about 2:1

Comment: call if the pot is offering you 2:1 or better

Comment: sorry, i mised it

Answer (score 0):

Well taking away the math, if you have a tell on that player you should fold as you are an underdog against all three hands.

Mathematically speaking, if you are heads up then in tournament for instance it makes sense to take a coin flip vs QQ (56%-44). For an all-in, AK is a big underdog to KK (30%-70%) and it is even worse vs AA (15%-85%).

If you are a novice I would advice you to never fold AK in tournaments in all-in situations. In most situations you will face coin flips but sometimes you will be a big favourite vs AQ-A2. Only AA and KK are scary cards but you have blockers vs both.

Comment: Can be an underdog and it still makes sense to call if you are getting proper odds

Comment: if you are facing allin preflop vs one player I doubt you will ever get right odds to call vs KK AA unless your Harrington's M is in a desperate situation (tournaments)

Comment: This can happen if there are other players who bet/call and then fold to e.g. an all-in by the big-blind.

Comment: @JimmyJames Yes, whether the other players have folded or not.  Or if it's a tournament and you have the other player covered and a chance to knock out a short stack.  So many consideratons.

Comment: @Michael I guess it's not called out explicitly but it's strongly implied that there is only one opponent left.  It would be a different odds calculation otherwise.